# Vue Component not showing text when called from blade.php file

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have a basic vue 2.6.11 component that lives in a laravel 6 application. It lives at `resources/js/components`. I create a basic component and then in my `app.js` file I have vue imported and I define my vue component. Then in my app.blade.php I use the vue component but the text within my `<template><div>Text here</div></template>` does not appear on the screen. The `<h1>` text appears but not the vue component text. I looked at other posts but the vue versions other questions on here use are 2-3 years too old and don't apply. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

TableDraggable.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Test Text</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('this component has been mounted');
        }
    }
</script>
```

What I am using in my app.blade.php file

```
<h1>This is a test to see if VUE is working</h1>
<table-draggable></table-draggable>
```

app.js snippet

```
//Bring in VUE and vue draggable
window.Vue = require('vue');
import VueDraggable from 'vuedraggable';
Vue.component('table-draggable', require('./components/TableDraggable'));
```

Comment: You see this?
            console.log('this component has been mounted');

Comment: In your app.js, what is the el being used as the scope? ie) const app = new Vue({ el:'#app', ... And in the markup of the page you are trying to use this component, is there a parent div with that id?

Comment: I do not see that. I don't have any errors in my browser or vue-browser console. I just have this message You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
backend.js:2237  vue-devtools  Detected Vue v2.6.11

Comment: @KurtFriars I am unsure what you mean. I think it just global scope in app.js.

Comment: If you have the default app.js Show us the root vue instance. Ie) the one created as const app = new Vue(..

Comment: I suppose I do not have a root vue instance. Should I create one in app.js? I am new to vue, sorry.

Comment: no worries :) Components are used by a Vue instance, and a vue instance is bound using the el: property. The el: is an id of an element in the html that it uses as its scope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217549/discussion-between-pa-gw-and-kurt-friars).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In app.js try the following:

```
...
window.Vue = require('vue');

import VueDraggable from 'vuedraggable';
Vue.use(VueDraggable);

import TableDraggable from './components/TableDraggable';
Vue.component('table-draggable', TableDraggable);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data() {
        return {};
    },
});
...
```

Then in some parent element of where you are using your component, make sure it has an id of app. eg:

```
<div id="app">
    <h1>This is a test to see if VUE is working</h1>
    <table-draggable></table-draggable>
</div>
```

This is a basic example of getting vue working on your site, and not necessarily the best way to be structuring your assets depending on your needs. The biggest considerations about how to structure these are how bulky your assets will become if you include everything in app.js.

Comment: Point taken, I will possibly import a separate file that contains by vue  components.